# Elegant way to set a mode of operation across multiple function files

Tags: matlab, octave

I've written a piece of code which calls numerous functions, which in turn also call several sub-functions.

I am calling the main file from the command line and supplementing the call with certain arguments to initiate certain modes I have accounted for.

E.g. `octave classify_file.m --debug <file>` would run in my custom debug mode, which sets a constant `debug` to `1` and subsequently outputs all plots and relevant variables. Omitting the argument outputs only 1 variable.

Similarily I have a `template` and a `histogram` mode, which essentially all do the same thing, except output some more variables, matrices and plots depending on the mode.

As it is now, I have to include the `debug`, `template` and `histogram` constants as arguments to each and every function if I want them to be influenced by the respective modes.

This is cumbersome and confusing, there has to be a better way. I've never worked with global variables, but would this be a good place to use one? What's an elegant solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation in which global variables will come in handy, although as you may be aware they are sometimes frowned upon, and can also have certain performance implications in matlab.  Personally I don't think passing the mode all the way down the call stack is too bad - although are you treating all 3 as separate arguments?  The least you could do is put them in a struct in your highest level function so that you only have 1 argument:

```
mode.debug = [whatever]
mode.histogram = [whatever]
mode.template = [whatever]
myFunction(mode);
```

OR, if you can only have one mode at a time what about some integer constants?

```
mode = MODE_DEBUG
```

or

```
mode = MODE_NONE
```

I would define the constants by creating short functions, this is how the `pi` constant works for example.

Finally, there is an alternative to global variables which I rather like, which is functions that use [persistent](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html) variables.  For example:

```
function m = debugMode(newValue)
  persistant isModeOn;

  if nargin > 0
    isModeOn = newValue
  end
  m = isModeOn;
end
```

This way you can call `debugMode(1)` to set it on, and you can call `m = debugMode` *anywhere* to get the value.